# Paragraphs are in bold

Tags: paragraphs, bold

You can see it: http://wstaw.org/m/2011/02/22/plasma-desktopRe1862.jpg

Page source:

```
\section{Esimese astme pealkiri}
\subsection{Alampealkiri}
\subsubsection{Veel madalam pealkiri}
\paragraph{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque mattis vestibulum mauris at tempor. Etiam sed dolor tortor, quis tristique erat. Aliquam et luctus lectus. Quisque ut nunc tempor velit ultrices vestibulum ut ut tortor. Curabitur ullamcorper metus nisl. Sed sem orci, vulputate ac placerat et, scelerisque non metus. Curabitur feugiat, dolor et tincidunt dictum, risus ante pretium nisl, sit amet consequat eros sapien tristique orci. Etiam nunc diam, tempor eget dictum id, tempor in ipsum. Mauris fringilla lacinia urna, id aliquet odio tristique a. Nulla viverra pellentesque libero, sed laoreet tortor tempus lacinia. Pellentesque tempor dictum tempus. Donec sed velit purus, quis pellentesque turpis. Vivamus non neque nisl, ac mattis dolor. Aliquam dictum fringilla tortor quis tempus. Aenean imperdiet, nulla eu laoreet porttitor, lectus elit semper dui, quis convallis lacus massa id eros. Cras convallis enim nec sapien ultrices vitae blandit diam rutrum. Praesent egestas felis non mi suscipit at molestie orci tristique. Ut hendrerit, libero sit amet commodo fermentum, odio nunc mattis magna, eu tempor nisl ligula non lorem.}
\paragraph{Morbi non egestas nisl. Maecenas eu ipsum justo, accumsan auctor ipsum. Vestibulum nec tortor justo. Morbi arcu nulla, luctus et aliquam a, fringilla ut diam. Nam suscipit, justo vel vulputate pretium, velit mauris adipiscing purus, eget molestie dolor nulla eu nunc. Nunc imperdiet lectus ac massa lacinia commodo. Duis sed dolor mauris, sed elementum ipsum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed id interdum massa. Integer condimentum justo in orci scelerisque accumsan. Aenean nibh ante, imperdiet in pretium ut, rutrum non diam. Aenean pellentesque elementum leo eget viverra. Proin pharetra elit id eros rhoncus facilisis.}
```

Main file code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Use Times New Roman font
\usepackage{txfonts}

% Make sections to uppercase
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\uppercase}{\thesection}{12pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{0pt}{24pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{0pt}{0pt}{24pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0pt}{24pt}

% set some margins
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=3cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}
\input{mk_titlepage.tex}
\input{mk_contents.tex}
\input{mk_page_1.tex}
\end{document}
```

How can I set font to be lighter?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but for future reference, you may want to ask on http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Using a pastebin is discouraged; just post the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like all section headers, `\paragraph` is bold by default. You could change this using the `\titleformat` command, just like you did for `\section`. However, you probably want to remove the `\paragraph` headers altogether and just write the text — you seem to be confusing the “paragraph” kind of header with a paragraph of text. You get a paragraph by default, without using any markup.

Comment: To add to that: paragraphs in *TeX are marked by empty lines between them.

Comment: Also, if you really want markup to do so, you can use `\par` (no arguments) to separate paragraphs. But a blank line is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might think the wrong way when you use `\paragraph{}`. In HTML, a paragraph is just a part of the usual text. However, in LaTeX it is the "lowest" heading.

If you still want to use it and want it not to be bold, then you can use:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize}}
\makeatother
```

Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148910/5645

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use `\paragraph{}{}` where one will start writing the desired sentences inside the second curly braces.

Comment: With some document classes, this can result in a lonesome period at the beginning of that element.  And it is almost never necessary -- and sometimes counterproductive -- to put the actual paragraph text within braces.