# How could make the topic of \paragraph not bold?

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I am writing a paper for a journal. So I download a template for LaTeX. But it does not define `\subsubsubsection`.

So I use:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}% for \subsubsubsection
\paragraph{Topic}\mbox{}\\
```

But 'Topic' is bold and subsub-topic is not bold. So how could I make subsubsub-topic is not bold?

I also found that there are different space in the first word of 1st section for several subsubsub-text.

E.g.

> 2.1.1.2 Topic
>
> First world...
>
> 2.1.1.3 Topic
>
> First world...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't do

```
\paragraph{Topic}\mbox{}\\
```

In `article` class `\paragraph` is defined as an *inline* heading. If you want a display heading you should adjust the definition rather than put `\mbox{}\\` after every heading (which looks horrible in the source and breaks LaTeX's attempts to control page breaking near headings)

You could use one of the packages for defining section heads or really it is as simple just to define directly.

```
\makeatletter

%\newcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
%                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
%                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
%                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

Commented out is the definition of subsubsection in article, you will need to look at the definition in your class. The definition of `\paragraph` follows, I have left it unchanged. You need the sign of the lengths to change (changing -1em to 1.5ex \@plus .23x will make it a display heading with a vertical skip the specified amount rather than an inline heading with a horizontal skip. Also of course if you don't want it bold, just take out the `\bfseries.

As you provided no example code in your question I can't be more specific.