# Add a space between the title and the text when using the \paragraph command

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, sections-paragraphs

How to add a space between the title and the text when using the `\paragraph` command?. 
PS. I'm using the `\elsarticle` for `\documentclass`.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[final,1p,times,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amssymb}%
\usepackage{verbatim}   
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage {minitoc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[authoryear,comma,longnamesfirst,sectionbib]{natbib} 
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue {hyperref}
\usepackage{numcompress}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
    \section{Export market}
    \subsection{The baseline small open economy}
    \paragraph {\textit{\textbf{Production}}}
    Export goods, $ X_{t}(i)$,are produced by export producers with a CES production function:
```

and my output is

[image]

Comment: You provide too little information. If I typeset the code that you show above with `\documentclass{elsarticle}` (after changing `paragrah` to `paragraph`) the output looks different. If you want us to help you, show the *complete* code of the document and make sure that it indeed compiles without errors and produces the output that you claim it does.

Comment: i i have added all the package i used

Comment: @haithem: ... and then some! Don't load packages more than once (like [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm)), and don't load superfluous packages if you don't use them (like [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum)). The latter is not problematic, but you won't order someone off a menu if you're not going to eat it...

Comment: Your document does not compile without errors. Is your input `latin1` or `utf8` encoded? (You have `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` as well as `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`. And you load some packages several times, like `amsthm`.

Comment: And the closing bracket is missing for the options of `hyperref`. And you load `natbib` three times. And `hyperref` should be loaded last. So don't be surprised if your document behaves strangely. And there is no `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. Have you tried to compile the code?

Comment: yes look at the output in the modified picture above

Comment: But you get lots of errors; look into the log file. Anyway: What exactly is now the problem to be solved? There *is* a space between the paragraph title and the following text that is wider than the usual space. Do you want to have it wider still? Or do you aim for something different?

Comment: the production should be as subsubsection using the paragrah comand,in others word it should not be in the same line with the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to redefine the `\paragraph` command to look more like the `\subsection` command, since `\paragraph` is typically defined to be inline rather than display.  Something like this should do it:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
    {-3.25ex \@plus-1ex \@minus-0.2ex}%
    {1.5ex \@plus 0.2ex}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Here's One}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

This will give you the following:

[image: Display Paragraph]

Just FYI:  searching Stackexchange would have turned up some solutions.  For example, this one is lifted from the answer [by David Carlisle, here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148895/how-could-make-the-topic-of-paragraph-not-bold); while it's not exactly what you asked, it does solve your problem.